# ST_Contains always return false

Tags: polygon, postgis-2.4

I'm definitely a 'geonewbie' and I'm trying to test if a point is contained inside a region. 
I have taken some certified data here:

https://www.istat.it/it/archivio/124086

getting **WGS84 UTM32N** for **2016**. Then I have imported the *Reg_2016_WGS84.shp* file with **shp2pgsql-gui**. The import was successful:

```
Importing with configuration: reg_2016_wgs84_new, public, geom, [myHome]/Limiti_2016_WGS84/Reg2016_WGS84/Reg_2016_WGS84.shp, mode=c, dump=1, simple=0, geography=0, index=1, shape=1, srid=4326
Shapefile type: Polygon
PostGIS type: MULTIPOLYGON[2]
Shapefile import completed.
```

I'm interested on region 6, so check for validity:

```
select ST_IsValid(a.geom) from 
public.reg_2016_wgs84_new a
where a.cod_reg = 6
```

Query says: **true**

Then trying to check a point that for sure is outside the region:

```
select a.*, St_contains(a.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(45.462360, 9.185939),4326))
from 
public.reg_2016_wgs84_new a
where a.cod_reg = 6
```

Query says: **false**

But also this point that ***for sure*** is inside the region got **false**:

```
SELECT a.*, St_contains(a.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(46.062340, 13.237270), 4326))
FROM 
public.reg_2016_wgs84_new a
where a.cod_reg = 6
```

So `ST_Contains` seems to return always false even if the MULTIPOLYGON is valid. May be I'm doing a big mistake somewhere...

My PostGis version:

```
POSTGIS="2.4.4 r16526" PGSQL="100" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.4" LIBJSON="0.12" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

Comment: @Vince thx, totally ignored that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch your coordinates in [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html); as with most functions in GEOS/GDAL environments, the order of coordinates has to be

- **`(X, Y, [Z])`**, or
- **`(Lon, Lat)`**

or you"ll find yourself looking at the wrong side of the world...

```
SELECT a.*,
       ST_Contains(a.geom, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(13.23727, 46.062340), 4326), 32632))
FROM   public.reg_2016_wgs84_new AS a
WHERE  a.cod_reg = 6
```

---

**Update:**

I totally ignored your CRS, but @Vince to the rescue; you will *also* need to set the right projection! If your data is in EPSG:32632 and you are passing in *Points* in EPSG:4326, it is bound to fail.

I updated the query above with [`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html).

Comment: The data source is marked as WGS84 UTM32N. Its EPSG should be 32632, so I imported again the regions setting SRID in shp2pgsql-gui to 32632. Now the query works properly. Still not clear where the CRS of the points come from, but it works with 4326, thanks guy!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution stands in the fact that: `ST_Contains(table1.geom, table2.geom)` returns `True` if table1.geom contains table2.geom, meaning table2 is inside table1.

This is the opposite of the documentation I have found about ST_contains()